# Html layout for emails with a scalable text block

Tags: html, css

I am creating the following layout that is to be used in emails and must be table-based, margins can not be used in it:

http://jsfiddle.net/j7eqL4h2/

In particular, I am trying to make these two tables 6 and 7:

```
                <!-- Table 6 -->
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="right" class="deviceWidth"
                       style="height: 70px; background-color: #102312; width: 100%;">
                    <tr></tr>
                </table>
                <!-- Table 7 -->
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="right" class="deviceWidth"
                       style="height: 100px; background-color: #181704; width: 100%;">
                    <tr></tr>
                </table>
```

to appear right after Area 2 (lightgreen), whereas Area 4 should be hidden (e.g., height could be 0), thus Area 6 and 7 are pulled up to Area 2 (lightgreen). Now, if the text in Area 5, becomes bigger (more lines are added) and goes out of Area 2, Area 4 appears and its height gets bigger pushing at the same time Area 6 and 7 downwards.

I think the structure of the layout has to be somehow changed, but just can't get it work. How can I produce this effect? Thank you for your help.